# Get s3 filename from filepicker.io after successful upload

Tags: filepicker.io

I've been using Filepicker.IO in order to upload files directly from the browser to the amazon s3 and most things are working fine, the only problem i'm facing now is that after the upload is done, i'm not getting the name of the file in the s3.

Filepicker js api is returning this object:

```
Object {url: "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/xxxxxxxxxxxxx", filename: "xyzhi.mp4", mimetype: "video/mp4", size: 36735, isWriteable: true}
```

Usually this object comes with a property named 'key' which has the name of the file in the S3.

This happens when the upload is not done from the local computer, if i pick a local file everything works ok, but if i pick a file from any of the providers (e.g Dropbox, Google Drive), i can't get the filename in the S3 server.

Thanks.

Comment: I should clarify, that the problem with Marcos is that the upload from Filepicker.io when using a service other than local computer upload (ie: Dropbox, File URL, Box, Webcam, etc) is not sending the file to the configured S3 bucket. That's why he is not getting the S3 file key, because Filepicker.io is not uploading the file to S3 when using other options besides local upload. What we need to know is why this is happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that you are using a function that is explicitly storing to S3, for instance `filepicker.pickAndStore` or `filepicker.store`. As noted in the [filepicker.io pick API documentation](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#pick), the "key" parameter on fpfiles returned specifically from the .pick() call are deprecated and not meant to be used.

Comment: In case anyone hits this, you will not receive the key if you are on a free plan.